# Swift 4 - 'substring(to:)' is deprecated - Alternative To My Code

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

My code was as below

```
   var theReview = addReview.text
    let len2 = addReview.text.utf16.count

    if len2 > 3000 {

        theReview = theReview?.substring(to: (theReview?.index((theReview?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 3000))!)

    }
```

My aim was to get the first 3000 characters of the text if it is longer than 3000 characters.

However, I get the warning below:

> 'substring(to:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript
>   with a 'partial range upto' operator

What can be an alternative to my code. I am not a very professional coder. So any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call `prefix(_:)` on `theReview` with the required `length`.

> **func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring**
>
> Returns a subsequence, up to the specified maximum length, containing
>   the initial elements of the collection.
>
> If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the
>   collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection

```
var theReview = addReview.text
theReview = String(theReview.prefix(3000))
```

**Note:** There is no need to check if the `theReview's length` exceeds `3000`. It will be handled by `prefix(_:)` itself.

Comment: I guess this could even be compressed to `let theReview = String(addReview.text.prefix(3000))`

Answer (score 1):

might this could help you

```
var theReview = addReview.text
theReview = String(theReview.prefix(3000))
```

Comment: See the answer by PGDev for a better use of `prefix()`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes i saw PGDev answer , better one

Comment: Even if string length under 3000 `.prefix` will still work.

Comment: @user28434 yes thats why we embed it in an if condition

Comment: @NaqeebAhmed, I mean `if` is not needed, in worst case you gonna get original string.

Answer (score 0):

Use String init with slice.

```swift
let index = theReview.index(theReview.startIndex, offsetBy: 3000)
theReview = String(theReview[theReview.startIndex..<index])
```

or `prefix` as mentioned in previous answers

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sure thing. but length check present in question.